# Not redirecting to Same Pagination (or Page) after successful operation. Laravel

Tags: php, pagination, laravel-5.4

I'm a newbee who needs help in laravel (not using javascript or ajax). I am created a CRUD operation and applied pagination to the displayed list of result. When I am deleting or altering any data in Pagination level 2 or more after successful completion of operation the page is redirected back to page 1. 
I thought of passing pagination data using Session and redirect after successful operation but I'm confused how to do. Second I think laravel provides a middleware for redirection(not sure) to proper page.

Thanks for the help. I will upload code whichever you guys need to review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I found how to do pagination properly.
That is when I delete any data from page 2 or above how to retain it.
I created a hidden field  where i stored current page number which i fetched using $_GET['page'].

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_GET['page']))
      $page = $_GET['page']; 
  else
      $page=1;
?>
 <form action="{{action('CrudController@destroy', $post->id)}}" method="post">
     {{csrf_field()}}
     <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
     <input name="page" type="hidden" value={{ $page}}>
     <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
 </form>
```

Now In my controller I modified my destroy method like this

```
public function destroy(Request $request, $id)
{
    if(DB::table('cruds')->where('id',$id)->first()){
        DB::table('cruds')->where('id',$id)->delete();
    }
    return redirect('/crud?page='.$request->input('page'));
}
```

This solved my problem. Anyways if any of you have any better solution please post I would like to try that one also. Now I am gonna try it using session and if I succeed I will share that one also.

Problem I am facing in Laravel is routes. We can write routes in so many ways that I am confused.